# How to refactor a large method when its components don't make sense on their own?

Tags: python, refactoring

I'm looking to refactor a very large method on a django `models.Manager`.  For the sake of clarity (as well as my sanity), I would like to break this up into its component parts.

This method takes in an object, uses information on that object to load a webpage, and based on the contents of that page it returns a new or existing object from the database.

---

Let's imagine that I'm trying to get a `Vehicle` corresponding to a certain webpage.  This might involve, among other things:

- loading the page in question
- finding the name of the vehicle from the page
- working out if a matching vehicle already exists
- determining, say, all the different colours I could paint the vehicle, and whether they've changed since I last looked at the page

At the moment, the method signature might look something like this:

```
class VehicleManager(models.Manager):
    def getForSale(self, sale):
        # lots and lots of code
```

I would like to break this up into smaller methods, each of which does one of the above bullet points.

---

The conceptual problem I'm having is that I'm not sure where to put the smaller methods.  They don't seem to belong on the `VehicleManager`, because:

- they're not things I can *do* to a set of `Vehicle` objects (eg, `Vehicle.objects.findNameOnPage` is nonsensical)
- a lot of them don't even use instance variables

---

I can think of a couple of ways to refactor this:

- Just create new methods, prefixed with an underscore, eg:

  ```
  def _findNameOnPage(self, page): # self is not used
  ```

  The problem with this approach is that the methods are more utility functions than true methods.
- Create static methods:

  ```
  @staticmethod
  def _findNameOnPage(page):
  ```

  This associates the methods with the class (good), but in doing so clutters the namespace (bad).
- Place the methods as module scope

  This doesn't clutter the namespace (good), but also makes it less clear that the methods are associated with the class (bad).

---

Is there an accepted pattern / way of achieving this in python?

Comment: One option you failed to list is to place the functions in local scope. If they have no value outside of `getForsale()`, then they can be nested functions inside `getForSale()`. This still allows you isolate code to function with limited responsibility.

Comment: Place the methods as module scope: while it may seem like you got random methods scattered in this module, you can check where they are imported and that's your relationship there.

Comment: This question may be more suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Robᵩ - I'm open to migration.  I was tossing up where to put it, so if anyone has a strong opinion either way I'm fine with the move.